# feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [POST]

Tags: java, exception, feign

When i am trying to hit the API via postman on my local system for the service I am getting this exception.

feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [POST] to [https://foo/foo/get] [ServiceNameFeignClient#search(SearchRequest)])]

Please if someone can suggest some help.

Basically while trying to hit the API via postman i am facing this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.